# TAR + create the dir under specific location

Tags: tar

I must to run the tar command only under /var/tmp in my Linux machine ( red-hat linux )
so I run the tar command. 
And directory "KIT" created under /var/tmp in place under /var/tmp/DIR/

What to change in the command in order to create the KIT directory under /var/tmp/DIR/ dir?

```
        cd /var/tmp
        tar zxvf /var/tmp/DIR/file.tar.gz
```

under /var/tmp I see

```
   KIT/
   KIT/STF-5/
   KIT/STF-5/SJ-GENER-363/
   KIT/STF-5/SJ-GENERONS-1.5-0/NYGDE
   KIT/STF-5/SJ-RESOUR-1.5-0/
   KIT/STF-5/SJ-RESAGER-1.5-0/NWERM
   KIT/STF-5/NETSNMP-0/
   KIT/STF-5/NETSNMP-5.3-0/NYNETSNMP
```

and what I need is to create the KIT under /var/tmp/DIR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tar zxvf /var/tmp/DIR/file.tar.gz -C /var/tmp/DIR/
```